# Node.js is it possible to disallow a client from accessing /register_success endpoint except through res.redirect()?

Tags: node.js, express

When a client successfully registers on my `node.js` app they are redirected to a success page,

```
res.redirect('/register_success');
```

However any client can access this endpoint by typing `www.mysite/register_success` into the address bar.

Is there a method available that can restrict clients from accessing this endpoint unless the router forwards them to it after a successful registration?  I'm searching but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to track state between page views.

Traditionally, this is done via a cookie which contains a session identifier, with session state stored server-side.  You can use [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), which does this for you.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session#example):

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.views) {
    req.session.views = {}
  }

  // get the url pathname
  var pathname = parseurl(req).pathname

  // count the views
  req.session.views[pathname] = (req.session.views[pathname] || 0) + 1

  next()
})

app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('you viewed this page ' + req.session.views['/foo'] + ' times')
})

app.get('/bar', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('you viewed this page ' + req.session.views['/bar'] + ' times')
})
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, very interesting.  I'm using `express-session` so if I'm understanding you correctly what I need to do is send a cookie before the redirect.  After that I need to disallow anyone that doesn't have that cookie from the `/register_success` endpoint?

Comment: `express-session` will set the cookie for you.  All you need to do is set/get data at `req.session`.  So, you could do something like `req.session.registered = true`.  And then in your handler for `/register_success` something like `if (!req.session.registered) { return res.sendStatus(403); }`.